# How to persist a value in Angular web app before login and use it after login?

Tags: angular, okta, angular11, okta-api

I am working on an Angular app which uses multi factor authentication using okta for login. Whenever a user login using credentials, it has to also verify through okta (push verification) as well. Once the okta verification is successful user is allowed to login.

This login flow is like this:

```
Step1. User enter creds
Step2. backend call fetches okta information
Step3. okta pop-up shows up
Step4. user verifies successfully
Step5. backend call is made and session is established
```

Now I want to show the same okta pop-up at a button click after the user has logged in.
But I need one information fetched in **Step2** of login. I am not able to save that information in session as session is not available at Step2.

Is there any way I can save information in Step2 so that I can reuse it even after Step5 is completed?

**NOTE** - I want to store an object

Comment: You can use `localStorage` or `IndexedDB` to store the information needed for the credentials (JWT etc)

Comment: localStorage I can't use, but not sure about IndexedDB, will checkout.